# ERROR : appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:run failed: Non zero exit: 1

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine

I have recently picked up a former employee's unfinished java appengine project. I have been trying to launch the app since this morning but i don't seem to be able to figure out what the problem is. 
I'm using java 8.
I did an mvn clean package through terminal and then ran another appengine maven build and got this:

*

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=C:\Users\ORVIFSTAGIERE\Documents\MesProjectJava\SiteOrvifMaven\website "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=49872:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Maven\apache-maven-3.5.4\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2017.3.4 com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] The project com.orvif.website:website:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT uses prerequisites which is only intended for maven-plugin projects but not for non maven-plugin projects. For such purposes you should use the maven-enforcer-plugin. See https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireMavenVersion.html
[INFO] 
[INFO] ---------------------< com.orvif.website:website >----------------------
[INFO] Building website 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:run (default-cli) > package @ website >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.4.1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ website ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:resources (default-resources) @ website ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 1 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:compile (default-compile) @ website ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.3:display-dependency-updates (default) @ website ---
[INFO] The following dependencies in Dependencies have newer versions:
[INFO]   com.google.appengine:appengine-api-1.0-sdk .......... 1.9.76 -> 1.9.78
[INFO]   com.google.appengine:appengine-api-stubs ............ 1.9.76 -> 1.9.78
[INFO]   com.google.appengine:appengine-testing .............. 1.9.76 -> 1.9.78
[INFO]   com.google.appengine:appengine-tools-sdk ............ 1.9.76 -> 1.9.78
[INFO]   com.google.cloud:google-cloud-storage .............. 1.81.0 -> 1.103.1
[INFO]   com.google.cloud.sql:mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8 ...
[INFO]                                                         1.0.14 -> 1.0.15
[INFO]   com.google.code.gson:gson ............................. 2.8.5 -> 2.8.6
[INFO]   com.google.truth:truth .............................. 1.0-rc2 -> 1.0.1
[INFO]   com.googlecode.objectify:objectify .................... 6.0.4 -> 6.0.6
[INFO]   com.zaxxer:HikariCP ................................... 3.3.1 -> 3.4.2
[INFO]   commons-codec:commons-codec ............................. 1.12 -> 1.14
[INFO]   javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api ....................... 3.1.0 -> 4.0.1
[INFO]   joda-time:joda-time ................................. 2.10.2 -> 2.10.5
[INFO]   junit:junit ...................................... 4.13-beta-3 -> 4.13
[INFO]   mysql:mysql-connector-java .......................... 8.0.16 -> 8.0.19
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.3:display-plugin-updates (default) @ website ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] The following plugin updates are available:
[INFO]   com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin ........ 1.3.2 -> 2.2.0
[INFO]   maven-clean-plugin ................................... 3.0.0 -> 3.1.0
[INFO]   maven-compiler-plugin ................................ 3.6.1 -> 3.8.1
[INFO]   maven-deploy-plugin ................................. 2.7 -> 3.0.0-M1
[INFO]   maven-enforcer-plugin ............................. 1.4.1 -> 3.0.0-M3
[INFO]   maven-install-plugin .............................. 2.5.2 -> 3.0.0-M1
[INFO]   maven-resources-plugin ............................... 3.0.2 -> 3.1.0
[INFO]   maven-site-plugin ...................................... 3.6 -> 3.8.2
[INFO]   maven-surefire-plugin .............................. 2.20 -> 3.0.0-M4
[INFO]   maven-war-plugin ..................................... 3.1.0 -> 3.2.3
[INFO]   org.codehaus.mojo:versions-maven-plugin .................. 2.3 -> 2.7
[INFO] 
[INFO] All plugins have a version specified.
[INFO] 
[INFO] Project defines minimum Maven version as: 3.5
[INFO] Plugins require minimum Maven version of: 3.0
[INFO] 
[INFO] No plugins require a newer version of Maven than specified by the pom.
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:3.0.2:testResources (default-testResources) @ website ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\ORVIFSTAGIERE\Documents\MesProjectJava\SiteOrvifMaven\website\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.6.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ website ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.20:test (default-test) @ website ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:3.1.0:war (default-war) @ website ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [website] in [C:\Users\ORVIFSTAGIERE\Documents\MesProjectJava\SiteOrvifMaven\website\target\website-1.0-SNAPSHOT]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [C:\Users\ORVIFSTAGIERE\Documents\MesProjectJava\SiteOrvifMaven\website\src\main\webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [1296 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: C:\Users\ORVIFSTAGIERE\Documents\MesProjectJava\SiteOrvifMaven\website\target\website-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:run (default-cli) < package @ website <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:run (default-cli) @ website ---
janv. 30, 2020 4:38:55 PM com.google.cloud.tools.appengine.cloudsdk.CloudSdk logCommand
INFOS: submitting command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\jre\bin\java.exe -Duse_jetty9_runtime=true -D--enable_all_permissions=true -Dappengine.sdk.root=C:\Users\ORVIFSTAGIERE\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java -cp C:\Users\ORVIFSTAGIERE\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\lib\appengine-tools-api.jar com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain --allow_remote_shutdown --disable_update_check --no_java_agent C:\Users\ORVIFSTAGIERE\Documents\MesProjectJava\SiteOrvifMaven\website\target\website-1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] GCLOUD: janv. 30, 2020 4:38:55 PM java.util.prefs.WindowsPreferences <init>
[INFO] GCLOUD: AVERTISSEMENT: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
[INFO] GCLOUD: janv. 30, 2020 4:38:55 PM com.google.appengine.tools.development.SystemPropertiesManager setSystemProperties
[INFO] GCLOUD: INFOS: Overwriting system property key 'java.util.logging.config.file', value 'C:\Users\ORVIFSTAGIERE\AppData\Local\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\java\config\sdk\logging.properties' with value 'WEB-INF/logging.properties' from 'C:\Users\ORVIFSTAGIERE\Documents\MesProjectJava\SiteOrvifMaven\website\target\website-1.0-SNAPSHOT\WEB-INF\appengine-web.xml'
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2020-01-30 16:38:56.084:INFO::main: Logging initialized @633ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.StdErrLog
[INFO] GCLOUD: 2020-01-30 16:38:56.138:WARN:oejs.AbstractConnector:main: Ignoring deprecated socket close linger time
[INFO] GCLOUD: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:346)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.open(ServerConnector.java:308)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.jetty9.JettyContainerService.connectContainer(JettyContainerService.java:309)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.createConnection(AbstractContainerService.java:268)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractInstanceHolder.createConnection(AbstractInstanceHolder.java:37)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractModule.createConnection(AbstractModule.java:73)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.Modules.createConnections(Modules.java:99)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.doStart(DevAppServerImpl.java:245)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.access$000(DevAppServerImpl.java:47)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:223)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl$1.run(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:221)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:404)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:45)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.run(DevAppServerMain.java:257)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:248)
[INFO] GCLOUD: Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector.openAcceptChannel(ServerConnector.java:342)
[INFO] GCLOUD:  ... 16 more
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.945 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-01-30T16:38:56+01:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:run (default-cli) on project website: Execution default-cli of goal com.google.cloud.tools:appengine-maven-plugin:1.3.2:run failed: Non zero exit: 1 -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Process finished with exit code 1
```

*

here's also the pom.xml file. Im guessing it may be a versions problem in one of my dependencies?:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

        <groupId>com.orvif.website</groupId>
        <artifactId>website</artifactId>

        <properties>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.showDeprecation>true</maven.compiler.showDeprecation>
            <archiveClasses>true</archiveClasses>
        </properties>

        <prerequisites>
            <maven>3.5</maven>
        </prerequisites>

        <dependencies>
            <!-- Compile/runtime dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-api-1.0-sdk</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.76</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <type>jar</type>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
                <version>1.19.4</version>
            </dependency>


            <!-- Test Dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-testing</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.76</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-api-stubs</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.76</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-tools-sdk</artifactId>
                <version>1.9.76</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.truth</groupId>
                <artifactId>truth</artifactId>
                <version>1.0-rc2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.13-beta-3</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2-beta</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
                <version>0.1.55</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
                <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
                <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
                <version>2.10.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.googlecode.objectify</groupId>
                <artifactId>objectify</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
                <version>1.12</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.sun.jna</groupId>
                <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.9</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
                <artifactId>platform</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-socket-factory-connector-j-8</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.14</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.16</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.0-b01</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.taglibs</groupId>
                <artifactId>taglibs-standard-impl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>appengine-gcs-client</artifactId>
                <version>0.8</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
                <version>1.81.0</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
                <version>1.4</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
                <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>

        <build>
            <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
            <resources>
                <resource>
                    <directory>src/main/java</directory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    </includes>
                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                </resource>
            </resources>
            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                    <artifactId>appengine-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.3.2</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <project>orvifgcp</project>
                        <version>1</version>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.3</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <phase>compile</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>display-dependency-updates</goal>
                                <goal>display-plugin-updates</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                    <configuration>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api</exclude>
                            <exclude>com.google.guava:guava</exclude> <!-- avoid android version -->
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.0</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6.1</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.5.2</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.20</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.6</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.2</version>
                </plugin>

                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                </plugin>


                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.4.1</version>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>enforce-maven</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <requireMavenVersion>
                                        <version>3.5</version>
                                    </requireMavenVersion>
                                    <requirePluginVersions>
                                        <message>Best Practice is to always define plugin versions!</message>
                                        <banLatest>true</banLatest>
                                        <banRelease>true</banRelease>
                                        <phases>
                                            clean,deploy,verify,appengine:run,appengine:deploy,appengine:update,appengine:devappaserver,site
                                        </phases>
                                    </requirePluginVersions>
                                </rules>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
    </project>
```

[image: ports]

[image: localhost browser]

Comment: It tells you what the error is: java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to localhost/127.0.0.1:8080. Do you have something else running on this port?

Comment: Hi jhell, it seems that only java.exe is runnning on port 8080. Nothing else seems abnormal. I added a snapshot of windows ports monitor.

Comment: Can you try to change the port number and check if is working?

Comment: Hi Marian, I am unable to change jetty's port number to one that isn't 8080. IntelliJ has the port locked down apparently.

Answer (score 0):

There is most likely another process that is listening on 8080 to find out what is that process, use this commands:

**in windows:**

```
netstat -ano | find "8080"
```

then stop it using:

```
taskkill -pid <PID> /f
```

**in Linux:**

```
netstat -tulpn | grep 8080
```

stop it using:

```
kill <PID>
```